# ios SWRevealViewController slide menu back

Tags: ios, objective-c, slidingmenu

I've implemented a sliding menu nav using SWRevealViewController (which works great). I was able to easily make it so i could swipe right to see the menu by adding this line to my

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

The menu nav would then show up on the left side of the screen (my main view controller would move to the right). However I am unable to swipe the screen back -- I am forced to tap on the main screen to have it move back (hiding the menu nav in the process). Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Did you connect this programmatically? Did you use a storyboard?

Comment: @neverbendeasy I'm working on the same library and tried to add the right_view in the controller through story board and it doesn't work. Do you think you can help with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517100/swrevealviewcontroller-rightviewcontroller)?