# Slide-Out Navigation Panel in ios from scratch

Tags: ios, objective-c, amslidemenu, mfslidemenu

I want to build a Slide out Navigation panel for both side (left & right) with `segue`. Some of the things i have to follow in this case. The left & right side menu table must be in `UIViewController` (not in `UITableViewController`) & all of the `viewController` is navigate through `UINavigationController` (Embedded).

I already try a ton of examples, But all of them are done by `UITableViewController`. Because of that i can't customize my left or right side Menu table according to my design.

If any one can give me some reference or similar tutorials, that would be very appreciable.

Thanks a lot in advanced. Have a good day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [MMDrawcontroller](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) and Pass LeftView, RightView and Centerview with Navigationcontroller. All three controllers are `UIViewController`. You can also add Left and Right View with NavigationController same as CenterView so you can push from left and right view.

```
CenterVC *objCenter = [[CenterVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"CenterVC" bundle:nil];
LeftVC *objleftVC = [[LeftVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"LeftVC" bundle:nil];
RightVC *objrightVC = [[RightVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RightVC" bundle:nil];

/*--- Init navigation for Center Controller ---*/
UINavigationController *_navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objCenter];
_navC.navigationBarHidden = YES;
_navC.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
MMDrawerController *drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                                        initWithCenterViewController:_navC
                                        leftDrawerViewController:objleftVC
                                        rightDrawerViewController:objrightVC];
[drawerController setShowsShadow:NO];
[drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];
[drawerController setMaximumLeftDrawerWidth:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-45.0];
[drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-45.0];
[drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
[drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];
[drawerController setShouldStretchDrawer:NO];

[drawerController
 setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
     MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock block;
     block = [[MMExampleDrawerVisualStateManager sharedManager]
              drawerVisualStateBlockForDrawerSide:drawerSide];
     if(block){
         block(drawerController, drawerSide, percentVisible);
     }
 }];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:drawerController animated:isAnimate];
```

Using **Storyboard** download (https://github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard) . Add `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` and then Replace or check Storyboard which was used in above demo and add code in AppDelegate as per demo.

So your demo project will look like below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the zip file I download from here, it doesn't have any storyboard file. :(
I am a little bit slow. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Tulon try this (https://github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard) maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to me great but the git you provide me last I can't make it run on my device. Because of `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` error.

Comment: @Tulon Create new project. Replace default storyboard with `MainStoryboard_iPhone`. add MMDraw Classes or POD. and add code in AppDelegate. also add `MMDrawerController+Storyboard`

Comment: I didn't see any `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` here. `MMDraw classes` >> you mean `MMDrawerController`?? Do you have any sample doc about this? I think this is the only one I can use in my project. Thanks a lot Ramani

Comment: @Tulon you can get that file from  (https://github.com/TomSwift/MMDrawerController-Storyboard)

Comment: Yes, I am got it earlier. But it has a clag error. THe pod isn't updated I presume. :(

Comment: @Tulon Thats why i told you create new project and add that file into your new project. **do not use pod** for `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` just add that file into your project. Do not use POD. take all files and add it manually.

Comment: In main project, there are `MMDrawerController+Storyboard` files and a folder named `KitchenSinkStoryboard` exist. In that folder I have `ExampleFiles` and `icons`. MMDrawerController and all the above files I included into my newly created project. And the story board is replaced by the sample's one MainStoryboard_iPhone. But unfortunately it is showing clang error just like the original. Just wondering It would be better if they provide some video tutorial or details instruction to embedded in project. I am not very familiar using pod. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: @Tulon I've done that and i didn't get any error. Get all MMDrawer files from (https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController). thats why i told you do not use POD. just select all files and add it into your project.

Comment: Ok. Can you give me full instruction step by step? I am waiting. :)
Right now I have a new created project. Now, there are two git you are talking about. One the original source and another is the error with clang. What should I follow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70568/discussion-between-chintan-maddy-ramani-and-tulon).

Answer (score 1):

Try [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). I think this might meet all your requirements. Its well documented so there's no need to say much here.

Comment: I already try with that. It only has "RevealControllerStoryboardExample2" for Storyboard, where they work with only left Menu side with `UITableViewController`. But I need left & right side menu and the tableView will embedded on `UIViewController`.

Comment: have a look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517100/swrevealviewcontroller-rightviewcontroller