# why does rightRevealToggle do nothing in 'SWRevealViewController'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to implement [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) but having some issue while trying to display the menu from the right.
In their documentation, in order to display it from the left we should do

```
[self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
[self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector (revealToggle:)];//this works
```

and if we want to do it from the right, we should change the `revealToggle` to`rightRevealToggle`.
But when I do that, nothing happens, What am I forgetting to do there?

Note: *I'm adding Swift as a tag, as it's the same with swift, just a different syntax.*

Comment: show us any your code, we know how documentation looks like :)

Comment: in my code, I have rightRevealToggle instead of revealToggle. what else should I do?

Comment: it is diffcult to say ,can you attach your project here , i will check

Comment: Try this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517100/swrevealviewcontroller-rightviewcontroller)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik why is it difficult to say? is changing revealToggle to rightRevealToggle not enough? what else do I need to do?

Comment: @Sanjeetverma thanks, That link helped me !

Comment: @wp42 I'm glad to help you.Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so of course, using `rightRevealToggle` was not enough, Just needed to set the `sw_rear` segue to `sw_right` segue.

I tried it before and it didn't work, trying again worked.